# TexFiled value is not updated after user's input in flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, textfield, textformfield

```
var nameController = TextEditingController();

TextEditingController nameController =  
                      TextEditingController(
                      text: snapshot.data![index].companyName .toString()); 

                      TextField(controller: nameController,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                            onPressed: () =>
                                                nameController.clear(),
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                                          ),
                                          hintText: 'Enter Party Name',
                                          border: InputBorder.none,
                                          contentPadding:
                                              const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                                        ),
                                      )
```

Comment: Please add some description and why you used `nameController ` two times?

Comment: Just for Define of Controller

Comment: when I click on textfiled and add another value than old value is repeating display on textfiled.

Comment: TextEditingController nameController =  
                      TextEditingController(
                      text: snapshot.data![index].companyName .toString());   <--I declare this  after  **  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: CustomerDetail.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) **

Answer (score 0):

//text: snapshot.data![index].companyName .toString() remove this line  from your coding

```
TextEditingController nameController =  
                      TextEditingController(
                      text: snapshot.data![index].companyName .toString()); 

                      TextField(controller: nameController,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                            onPressed: () =>
                                                nameController.clear(),
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                                          ),
                                          hintText: 'Enter Party Name',
                                          border: InputBorder.none,
                                          contentPadding:
                                              const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                                        ),
                                      )
```

edited answer

```
TextEditingController nameController =  
                      TextEditingController(
                      ); 

                      TextField(controller: nameController,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                            onPressed: () =>
                                                nameController.clear(),
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                                          ),
                                          hintText: 'snapshot.data![index].companyName .toString()',
                                          border: InputBorder.none,
                                          contentPadding:
                                              const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                                        ),
                                      )
```

Comment: But i was  fetching value from api  ..so if i Remove this however i print initial value from api ?

Comment: Plzz see My Above Post Commeet

Comment: ohk i don't know this thing. so you have to set this value as hint in textformfeild not into direct controller

Comment: answer has been edited

Comment: if I put this on hintext so ,  how i can display of "Enter Name" as for hint ?

Comment: its direct display vlaue

Comment: ohk can you specify your problem with screenshot

Comment: write only string instead of snapshot data. `var value=snapshot.data![index].companyName .toString().  TextEditingController nameController =  
                      TextEditingController(text:value
                      ); `.          but note this line of texteditingcontroller must be outside of stream builder or futurebuilder if you are using!!

Comment: textEditingController nameController = TextEditingController( text: snapshot.data![index].companyName .toString()); <--I declare this after ** if (snapshot.hasData) { return ListView.builder( itemCount: CustomerDetail.length, itemBuilder: (context, index) **

Comment: see my above comment